# Updating SVN in Mavricks

Tags: macos, svn

I'm trying to update my SVN install to the latest version and found this walkthrough

[http://samoldak.com/updating-to-svn-1-8-for-mac-os-x-10-8/][1]

But when I got to the line with just the `make` command I got this error:

`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

And I've really no idea what to do next.  Looking in the subversion directory in my downloads directory I have a file called `Makefile.in` should the command be `make Makefile.in`?

**Edit:**

Seems that the symbolic link I was creating was for Mountain Lion 10.8 not Mavericks 10.9 ... so now my C compiler works but I'm getting another error now:

checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/Users/jamesgreen/Downloads/subversion-1.8.0/serf':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use`--host'.
See `config.log' for more details

Comment: If configure complains on OSX with "cannot run C compiled programs", it might help to set the C compiler to clang (gcc might be assumed).

    export CC=clang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate the Makefile probably by running something along the lines of:

```
./configure --quiet && make -s
sudo make install
```

Comment: I just get the following error `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

Comment: Download Apple's XCode from the appstore (free)

Comment: Already have 5.1.1 and the command line tools installed.

Comment: Doesn't look like it, you need the C compiler to create a program from source code. If you don't know what you are doing, better stick to a binary like the ones that come with command line tools (svn is still in there I guess), or use homebrew's packages.

Comment: I've gotten past that point and I'm having a different problem now ... walking away and giving up isn't a way to learn though is it.

Comment: Try  ./configure --help

Comment: Turns out that I didn't have the command line tools installed so did `xcode-select --install` which installed them and then I carried on with the other commands and its now happily chugging through the compilation.  Thanks for your help datasmid!!

Comment: Well that was an education, all completed and created a new bash profile and `svn --version` now returns 1.8.0 ...

Answer (score 0):

I can't suggest [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) enough for this, just for future reference.

Comment: Ok, I'll definitely check that out in the future, thanks.